# Genera definition of difference between two polynomials when one has a shift

Tags: polynomials

I have two n (likely 4-6, but not always the same, and i'm curious if there is a general definition) degree polynomials defined as vectors containing the coefficient values. I can get the difference between the two polynomials easily by just subtracting the two sets of coefficients. But i'm not sure what to do if i have one of them shifted by $\Delta x$ .

So far what i have is:

$a(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{4}{a_i x^i}$

$b(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{4}{b_i x^i}$

I can get the difference $b(x) - a(x)$ by simply

$b(x) - a(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{4}{(b_i - a_i)x^i}$

But what if i have one of the polynomials is shifted, I'm not entirely sure what a general formula is (though from doing it by hand for n=4, it probably has something to do with binomial expansion).

How do i define $b(x-\Delta x) - a(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

It has everything to do with binomial expansion. For ease of notation, let me call the offset $r$ instead of $\Delta x$. So
$$b(x - r) = \sum_{k=0}^n b_k(x - r)^k
= \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^k\binom ki b_kr^{k-i}x^i$$
The sum can be rearranged to $$b(x - r) = \sum_{i=0}^nx^i\sum_{k=i}^n \binom ki b_kr^{k-i}$$.

And thus $$b(x-r) - a(x) =\sum_{i=0}^n \left(\sum_{k=i}^n \binom ki b_kr^{k-i} - a_i\right)x^i$$